# How to solve facebook login plugin configurator error?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I am using Facebook Login Pluginator(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button#plugin-configurator). On click of that button it will open popup itself(As pop up is opening after click event so browser will not block popup).There is error message for developer like below.

"You are using a display type of 'popup' in a large browser window or tab. For a better user experience, show this dialog with our JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type. The SDK will choose the best display type for each environment. Alternatively, set height and width on your window.open() call to properly size this dialog if you have special requirements precluding you from using the SDK. This message is only visible to developers of your application."

How can i fix that?
I am using v5.0 facebook js sdk.[image]

Comment: The button has no way to explicitly specify this. Ignore the warning, if it does not affect functionality. If you want the level of control the message talks about, a place where you can specify what size popup to render - then you will have to switch to using the FB.login method.

Comment: Regarding `FB.login`, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v5.0 does not even mention that parameter any more, so I think they might have removed it by now.

Comment: @04FS Thanks for reply. Facebook login popup will open automatically on click of this login plugin configurator. So if i want to use this plugin then i can not use FB.login method.

Comment: That’s right, they are two different ways of doing basically the same thing. The Login Button is more a configure / copy&paste thing, whereas using FB.login requires you to do a bit more of the scripting yourself.

Comment: @04FS I used plugin configurator so my login with facebook detect currently login facebook user in browser and display button with image. so is there any way to achieve this without above error?

Comment: Non-developers of your app won’t get to see this anyway.

Comment: @04FS is there any chance due to this error Facebook reviewer reject app review?